# Excel VBA sort Listbox data if not numeric to bottom

Tags: excel, vba, sorting, listbox

I am using the below code to sot my Listbox data numerically. I use the following IF statement to check if data is numeric (some data is not):

```
If IsNumeric(.List(i, 4)) And IsNumeric(.List(j, 4)) Then
```

My Listbox data is sorted correctly. However because of the above IF statement the sorting process ignores non-numeric data. **I need to sort the non numeric data to the bottom of the Listbox.**

```
Public Sub BubbleSort()

Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim Temp4 As Variant, Temp3 As Variant, Temp2 As Variant, Temp1 As Variant, Temp0 As Variant
With Plybooks.ListBox1
    For i = 0 To .ListCount - 2
        For j = i + 1 To .ListCount - 1
            If IsNumeric(.List(i, 4)) And IsNumeric(.List(j, 4)) Then
                If CLng(.List(i, 4)) > CLng(.List(j, 4)) Then
                    Temp4 = CLng(.List(j, 4))
                    .List(j, 4) = .List(i, 4)
                    .List(i, 4) = Temp4
                    Temp3 = .List(j, 3)
                    .List(j, 3) = .List(i, 3)
                    .List(i, 3) = Temp3
                    Temp2 = .List(j, 2)
                    .List(j, 2) = .List(i, 2)
                    .List(i, 2) = Temp2
                    Temp1 = .List(j, 1)
                    .List(j, 1) = .List(i, 1)
                    .List(i, 1) = Temp1
                    Temp0 = .List(j, 0)
                    .List(j, 0) = .List(i, 0)
                    .List(i, 0) = Temp0
                End If
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```

[image: Listbox Image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your list is not sorted correctly because when one of the two values is not numeric, your sort routine doesn't do anything.

Common solution when sorting a list of values (objects) that are not directly comparable is to write a custom function that compares two values. The sort function calls this function every time it needs to compare two values.

For your case, the function could look like this:

```
Function IsLarger(v1 As Variant, v2 As Variant) As Boolean
    
    ' Compare 2 values and return
    '   True if first value is larger
    '   False if second value is larger
    
    ' Comparing:
    ' When v1 and v2 are numeric, compare the values
    ' When only one of those values is numeric, that value is considered a smaller
    ' When both values are non-numeric, make a string compare
    
    If IsNumeric(v1) And IsNumeric(v2) Then
        IsLarger = (Val(v1) > Val(v2))
    ElseIf IsNumeric(v1) Then
        IsLarger = False
    ElseIf IsNumeric(v2) Then
        IsLarger = True
    Else
        IsLarger = (UCase(v1) > UCase(v2))
    End If
            
End Function
```

You can replace the two nested if-statements in your Sort-Routine simply with

```
If IsLarger(.List(i, 4), .List(j, 4)) Then
```

Comment: This worked perfectly - although I did need to ensure that non-numeric data was first modified to have a string as its value, otherwise I had a run-time error: "invalid use of Null". Thanks