# Excal Listbox Bubble-sort running slow on large amount of Data

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, bubble-sort

I use the following code to sort the data in a multicolumn Listbox. It sorts based on the numeric data in the 5th column. It works fine but is really slow when there is a large amount of data in the Listbox.

Any ideas on a quicker solution?

```
Public Sub BubbleSort()

Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim Temp4 As Variant, Temp3 As Variant, Temp2 As Variant, Temp1 As Variant, Temp0 As Variant, temp4string As String


With Plybooks.ListBox1
    For i = 0 To .ListCount - 2
        For j = i + 1 To .ListCount - 1
                If IsLarger(.List(i, 4), .List(j, 4)) Then
                    Temp4 = CLng(.List(j, 4))
                    .List(j, 4) = .List(i, 4)
                    .List(i, 4) = Temp4
                    Temp3 = .List(j, 3)
                    .List(j, 3) = .List(i, 3)
                    .List(i, 3) = Temp3
                    Temp2 = .List(j, 2)
                    .List(j, 2) = .List(i, 2)
                    .List(i, 2) = Temp2
                    Temp1 = .List(j, 1)
                    .List(j, 1) = .List(i, 1)
                    .List(i, 1) = Temp1
                    Temp0 = .List(j, 0)
                    .List(j, 0) = .List(i, 0)
                    .List(i, 0) = Temp0
                End If
        Next j
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Load the list into an array, sort that, then put it back. :)

Comment: I fear we have entered a loop here Rory! Not got a clue on that one, trying to look through the last one you helped me with... Will see if I can propose something, but again - any help much appreciated, may take me a while!

Answer (score 0):

For the array suggestion:

```
Dim data
data = Plybooks.ListBox1.List
For i = Lbound(data) To UBound(data) - 1
    For j = Lbound(data) + 1 To UBound(data)
            If IsLarger(data(i, 4), data(j, 4)) Then
                Temp4 = CLng(data(j, 4))
                data(j, 4) = data(i, 4)
                data(i, 4) = Temp4
                Temp3 = data(j, 3)
                data(j, 3) = data(i, 3)
                data(i, 3) = Temp3
                Temp2 = data(j, 2)
                data(j, 2) = data(i, 2)
                data(i, 2) = Temp2
                Temp1 = data(j, 1)
                data(j, 1) = data(i, 1)
                data(i, 1) = Temp1
                Temp0 = data(j, 0)
                data(j, 0) = data(i, 0)
                data(i, 0) = Temp0
            End If
    Next j
Next i
Plybooks.ListBox1.List = data
```

though if you could sort the data before you populate the list at the start, it would be better. I don't know why you need a separate `IsLarger` function rather than just using `>`?

[image]

Comment: because of https://stackoverflow.com/q/64535875/7599798

Comment: Hi @Rory, sort is not working as expected, should be lowest first ascending. Non-numeric at the bottom. I've added an example of what I am getting at the moment

Answer (score 0):

Your bubble is incorrect. Below is the generic bubble sort. Also, bubble sort is inherently slow on large amounts of data.

```
  sort (A, n)       // bubble sort array A[0..n-1]
  
    k= n-1;         // k holds position of last interchange. All higher elements are sorted.
    while (k > 0)
    {
        l= 0;
        for (j=0; j < k; j++)
        {
            if (A[j] > A[j+1])
            {
                tmp   = A[j];
                A[j]  = A[j+1];
                A[j+1]= tmp;
                l= j;
            }
        }
        k= l;       // remember last exchange. All higher elements are sorted.
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Bubble Sort is slower compared to other sort algorithms. See a time complexity comparison on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Comparison_of_algorithms)

You could sort the entire list by using a predefined method:

```
Dim arr2D as Variant
With Plybooks.ListBox1
    arr2D = .List
    Sort2DArray arr2D, 4 '4 being the exact column index you want to sort by
    .List = arr2D
End With
```

For example you could use a stable **QuickSort** adaptation that I've created a while ago. See this [repo](https://github.com/cristianbuse/VBA-ArrayTools/blob/master/Code%20Modules/LibArrayTools.bas) and look for the **Sort2DArray** function

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work as a quicker alternative to the bubble sort. It sorts in ascending numerical order with non-numeric data at the btm of the list

```
Dim data
data = Plybooks.ListBox1.List
For i = LBound(data) To UBound(data) - 1
    For j = LBound(data) To UBound(data)
            If IsLarger(data(j, 4), data(i, 4)) Then
                Temp4 = CLng(data(i, 4))
                data(i, 4) = data(j, 4)
                data(j, 4) = Temp4
                Temp3 = data(i, 3)
                data(i, 3) = data(j, 3)
                data(j, 3) = Temp3
                Temp2 = data(o, 2)
                data(o, 2) = data(j, 2)
                data(j, 2) = Temp2
                Temp1 = data(i, 1)
                data(i, 1) = data(j, 1)
                data(j, 1) = Temp1
                Temp0 = data(i, 0)
                data(i, 0) = data(j, 0)
                data(j, 0) = Temp0
                Temp5 = data(i, 5)
                data(i, 5) = data(j, 5)
                data(j, 5) = Temp5
            End If
   Next j
Next i
Plybooks.ListBox1.List = data
```